# .NET Core 3.1 AWS Lambda Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.1.1.0

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my aws-lambda-tools-default.json

```
{
  "Information": [
    "This file provides default values for the deployment wizard inside Visual Studio and the AWS Lambda commands added to the .NET Core CLI.",
    "To learn more about the Lambda commands with the .NET Core CLI execute the following command at the command line in the project root directory.",
    "dotnet lambda help",
    "All the command line options for the Lambda command can be specified in this file."
  ],
  "profile": "PP",
  "region": "RR",
  "configuration": "Release",
  "framework": "netcoreapp3.1",
  "s3-prefix": "API/",
  "template": "serverless.template",
  "template-parameters": "",
  "msbuild-parameters": "--self-contained true"
}
```

When I publish this to Lambda, no errors happen. But when I run the api, I get this error on CloudWatch:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.1.1.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>
> 23 Aug 2021 09:10:44,882 [WARN] (invoke@invoke.c:331 errno: None)
> run_dotnet(dotnet_path, &args) failed
>
> Failed to execute the Lambda function. The dotnet CLI failed to start
> with the provided deployment package.  Please check CloudWatch logs
> for this Lambda function to get detailed information about this
> failure.: LambdaException

Does this have anything to do with me compiling it as a self contained app?

When I compile it on my local PC, it runs without any issue. This is the csproj on my local PC

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
    <!-- This property makes the build directory similar to a publish directory and helps the AWS .NET Lambda Mock Test Tool find project dependencies. -->
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

EDIT: I had to add the nuget packages for System.Runtime.Loader and System.IO.Pipelines.

However, I discovered that PublishTrimmed caused this error to reappear as well.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?  Was it having `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>` in your csproj?

Comment: Hi @PhilipPittle, yeah. PublishTrimmed is a problem. Not sure why it doesn't work with my package.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to .NET 6
To migrate existing .NET Lambda functions to the new .NET 6 runtime:

1. Open the csproj or fsproj file. Set the TargetFramework element to net6.0.
2. Open the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file, if it exists:
3. Set the function-runtime field to dotnet6.
4. Set the framework field tonet6.0. If you remove the field, the value is inferred from the  project file.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/